# VBA connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba

I am having trouble when connecting VBA to SQL Server:

```
Sub ConnectSQLServer()

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn As String

Dim par As ADODB.Parameter
Dim strSQL As String

strConn = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=CHU-AS-0004;DATABASE=RTC_LaplaceD_DEV;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open strConn

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.Version"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

rs.Open = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Version]"

cmd.Execute rs
Set conn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing


sConnString = ""
End Sub
```

I just want to select all values from the table named `[dbo].[Version]`, but when I execute it, I get an error:

> Compile error: Expected Function or Variable'

and the line with `rs.Open` is highlighted.

Would you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[`Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/open-method-ado-recordset) is a method, and cannot be set with an `=`.

You probably want something like this:

```
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Version]", conn
```

Once you have called `Open`, then you can iterate through the Recordset's rows using the [`EOF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/bof-eof-properties-ado) property and the [`MoveNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/movefirst-movelast-movenext-and-moveprevious-methods-ado) method:

```
Do While Not rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(1)
    'You could also use rs!FieldName, where FieldName is the name of a column
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following:

```
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Version]"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

Set rs = cmd.Execute

Do While Not rs.EOF
    'do something with rs.Fields(0) '
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
Set conn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
```

rs.Fields is a zero based collection that means that the first field is 0, not 1.
You can get subsequent fields by rs.Fields(1), rs.Fields(2) etc. Or you can use Field names, with the syntax rs.Fields("MyFieldName").

Note when using a string command ("SELECT * FROM ..") the CommandType is adCmdText. The syntax for the Recordset is SET rs = cmd.Execute.  Also you must invoke MoveNext in your loop, otherwise you get stuck in the loop!